# ¿Como puedo repetir el ciclo hasta opcion 3?

Tags: java, eclipse, bucle-for, condiciones, consola

comunidad. Espero que esten teniendo un buen dia.

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio basico simulando un cajero automatico. El codigo compila bien. Lo que yo quiero hacer (Y no me sale) es generar que el codigo se vuelva a ejecutar en modo ciclico hasta la opcion 3 y que termine al presionar opcion 4. El codigo de esta manera corre, pero termina de ejecutar cada instrucion y ahi termina. Por ende, no me da lugar a poner la opcion 4 "Salir" porque obviamente, termina antes. Estaria muy agradecido que me pudieran brindar una ayuda. Saludos!
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int saldo = 5000, deposito, extraccion, opciones = 4, opcion;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(
            "Por favor, introduce una opcion \n1: Consulta de saldo. \n2: Retiro de efectivo. \n3: Deposito de efectivo. \n4: Salir ");
            opcion = in.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < opciones; i++) {
        if (i == 1 && opcion == 1) {
            System.out.println("Su saldo es de " + saldo);
        } else if (i == 2 && opcion == 2) {
            System.out.println("Por favor, ingresa el monto a retirar...");
            extraccion = in.nextInt();
            int retiro = saldo - extraccion;
            System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de " + retiro);

        }else if(i==3 && opcion==3) {
            System.out.println("Por favor, ingresa el monto a depositar..");
            deposito=in.nextInt();
            int ingreso=saldo+deposito;
            System.out.println("Su nuevo saldo es de " + ingreso);
        }
        else if(i==4&&opcion==4) {
            System.out.println("Muchas gracias por utilizar el sistema de Gestion Bancaria");
        }
    }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En tu código no estás utilizando una estructura de control cíclica continua, la cual para tu caso debe ser:

```
while (opcion != 4) {
//Tu código
}
```

Y para la parte selectiva de las opciones que brindas, en vez de `if` es recomendable usar:

```
switch(opcion){
     case 1:
         System.out.println("Su saldo es de " + saldo);
     break;
     //Agrega tus otras opciones
}
```

Como comentario extra, en la opción 3 no estas actualizando el valor del saldo depositado en la variable `saldo`

Comment: Está usando el for:  for (int i = 0; i < opciones; i++) {
        if (i == 1 && opcion == 1) {

Comment: Cierto, aunque es ciclo finito y requiere salir solo con la opción 4. Gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score -1):

Cambia el for por esto:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= opciones; i++)
```